# How do you restart this switch statement when the default case is accessed?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am VERY new to programming...
What can I do to make the switch statement start over when the default case is promted (for example when you enter "5"). Any help would be great!

I saw a similar question about this, but I couldn't use the answers.

```
int column= StdOut.println();
switch(column) {
   case 0: StdOut.println("Good");
           break;
   case 1: StdOut.println("Ok");
           break;
   case 2: StdOut.println("Bad");
           break;
   default: 
           break;
}
```

Comment: You most likely want to use a loop e.g. [`for` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). It's impossible to tell without seeing a more complete example.

Comment: You'd need a loop to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Surround it in a loop and add a variable that breaks the loop when you reach something you like:

```
int column= StdOut.println();
boolean isBad = true;
do{
    switch(column) {
       case 0: StdOut.println("Good");
           isBad = false;
           break;
       case 1: StdOut.println("Ok");
           isBad = false;
           break;
       case 2: StdOut.println("Bad");
           isBad = false;
           break;
       default: 
           isBad = true;
           break;
    }
}while(isBad);
```

Comment: This will cause infinite loop.

Comment: It made an infinite loop... but I used a variation of this (and the other answer given) and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```java
while(true) {
    ....
    switch (...) {
    case ....:
        ....
        break; // Exit switch statement, but not the loop
    // More cases here
    default:
        continue; // Go to the next iteration of the loop
    }
    break; // Exit the loop
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped!